# Experimental design to estimate the sample size

Tags: classification, multivariate-analysis, experiment-design, sample-size

I've been newly introduced to Experimental Design and I am wondering about its possible connection with multivariate classification models.
Is it possible to build a DoE able to predict which is the minimum sample size (in terms of elements per class) for a classification model? Perhaps using the accuracy of the prediction as response value?

I know that, for my specific field, at least 100 elements each should be considered for a stable model, but I'd like to try to assess it with a DoE (i.e., as an alternative to Cross Validation on growing data set). Can you suggest me some options?